# Sign into GitLab with OAuth2 Custom provider does not map user information

Tags: oauth, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I've installed Gitlab-CE on a CentOS VM and am trying to configure the [Sign On with an generic OAuth2 provider](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth2_generic.html), to be more specific am actually using [IBM Security Access Manager 9.0.6](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_9.0.6/com.ibm.isam.doc/config/concept/OAuthEndpoints.html#oauthendpoints).

So far **Sign On** works after tweeking a bit the [omniauth-oauth2-generic gem configuration](https://gitlab.com/satorix/omniauth-oauth2-generic) :

I do see the SSO Button :
[image: SSO Button]

And on the administration area i do find my user with the oauth2 identity provider :
[image]

My problem is that the user information is not set when the user signs on :
[image]

Here it's my omniauth configuration :

```rb
#https://gitlab.com/satorix/omniauth-oauth2-generic
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['oauth2_generic']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
  {
    'name' => 'oauth2_generic',
    'app_id' => '9gzCzRKeiipexDRXsJOJ',
    'app_secret' => 'mysecret',
    'args' => {
      client_options: {
        'site' => 'https://example.com', # including port if necessary
        'authorize_url': '/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/authorize',
        'token_url': '/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token',
        'user_info_url' => '/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/userinfo'
      },
      user_response_structure: {
        root_path: [],
        id_path: ['sub'],
        attributes: {
          nickname: 'sub',
          name: 'name',
          first_name: 'given_name',
          last_name: 'family_name'
        }
      }
      # optionally, you can add the following two lines to "white label" the display name
      # of this strategy (appears in urls and Gitlab login buttons)
      # If you do this, you must also replace oauth2_generic, everywhere it appears above, with the new name.
      #name: 'IBM ISAM', # display name for this strategy
      #strategy_class: "OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2Generic" # Devise-specific config option Gitlab uses to find renamed strategy
    }
  }
]
```

And my user info endpoint returns :

```
{ "sub":"XCQX342",
  "nickname": "Kalem",
  "name": "My name",
  "given_name": "My name",
  "family_name": "My surname",
  "email": "myemail@example.com"
}
```

I've compare my configuration with http://lifeinide.com/post/2017-08-30-jetbrains-hub-as-oauth2-provider-for-gitlab/ but i don't see what am doing wrong, and why gitlab is not able to my parse the user attributes.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are resolved your problem.

If not :

Try direct to set field as in this case

https://gitlab.com/satorix/omniauth-oauth2-generic/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2_generic.rb#L20

Simural  as you set there

```
user_response_structure: {
  root_path: [],
  id_path: ['sub'],
  attributes: {
    nickname: 'sub',
    name: 'name',
    first_name: 'given_name',
    last_name: 'family_name',
    email: 'email'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I've dropped this issue a moment ago and used the SAML provider. I don't have a test environement so i can't test your answer. Let's hope this helps someone else.